# How to find which .dll is causing issue?

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to run MassTransit on my server; on start up it gives below error in event viewer. Is there any way I can log more detail about exception where it will show which exact .dll is causing error ? As per my understanding I have copied all the required .dlls in folder. It works on my local machine. Is there anyway I can override or look or log from AssemblyScanner.

Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at MassTransit.Host.AssemblyScanner.<>c.<GetAssemblyRegistrations>b__5_10(Assembly x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MassTransit.Host.AssemblyScanner.GetAssemblyRegistratio...
```

Comment: Which version of MassTransit?

Comment: // Assembly MassTransit.Host, Version 1.0.0.0

[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows=true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default)]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("RapidTransitHost")]

Comment: Sadly that didn't help since the assembly tag is missing.

Comment: [assembly: AssemblyCompany("RelayHealth")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("RapidTransitHost")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright \x00a9 RelayHealth 2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("f8548d43-38aa-439d-997c-84621fb65b9b")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4.5")]

Comment: That has to be really, really old, because any recent version would have the proper MassTransit version on it. (something like 3.5.5).

Comment: The assembly scanning was changed in September of 2016, so yeah, really old.

Comment: It is already working on my local machine; it does not work on server. So obviously I am am missing some .dll. I have checked multiple times but I am not able to find which .dll is causing this issue. Is there anyway I can intercept AssemblyScanner that call to find out which exact .dll is causing issue. It is not possible to upgrade right away as we need to do coordinated upgrade for all services.